# Set default printer settings libreoffice

Tags: printing, libreoffice

Although I set the default printer settings through the "printing" manager to NoTumbleDuplex, the LibreOffice print dialog properties isn't defaulted as NoTumbleDuplex.  How can I set the NoTumbleDuplex setting as default on libreoffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [LibreOffice Help](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Setting_up_Printer_and_Fax_Under_UNIX_Based_Platforms) for detailed informations.

In short - execute `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/spadmin`.
This will tweak the file `~/.config/libreoffice/3/user/psprint/psprint.conf`

If you want to tweak the system wide setting have a look etc `/etc/libreoffice/psprint.conf`.

Comment: I'm using LibreOffice 4. Using `spadmin` allows me to change the default settings of the printer as you describe (I want to set b/w printing per default, not colorful). Also a file `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/psprint/psprint.conf` is created. But it does not seem to contain any information about the color printing. Also if I rename the folder `libreoffice` and start LibreOffice again, it is still set to b/w, so this specific setting is stored somewhere else.

Comment: I've found the solution to my previous comment and added it to your answer.

Comment: GUI applet to change default printer settings would be very helpful. Time passed, may be one already exist?